# How to record absolute position of mouse using Python "mouse" library

Tags: python, mouseevent, mouse, absolute

I want to use `mouse` library to record mouse events, but its position is relative. How can I set the recorder to record the absolute position?

```
import mouse

events = mouse.record()  # record until clicking right button
mouse.play(events[:-1])  # skip right button clicked
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to solve your problem :

```
import mouse
import pyautogui

def record_mouse_events():
    events = []
    initial_position = pyautogui.position()

    def on_event(event):                           
        # Check if the right mouse button is clicked (event.button == "right")
        if event.event_type == "down" and event.button == "right":
            mouse.unhook(on_event)  # Stop recording when right mouse button is clicked
        else:
            absolute_position = (initial_position[0] + event.x, initial_position[1] + event.y) 
            events.append(mouse.MouseEvent(event.event_type, absolute_position, event.button))

    mouse.hook(on_event)            
    return events

recorded_events = record_mouse_events()

for event in recorded_events:
    print(event)
```